# How can I find the greatest value of this expression?

Tags: inequality

This is my problem. Find the greatest of the expression 
$$P = x^3 + 2y^3 +2x-y-1,$$
knowing that
$$x^2 + y^2 -x-y=0. $$
I tried. We have
$$x^2 + y^2 -x-y=0 \Leftrightarrow \left (x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right )^2 + \left(y-\dfrac{1}{2}\right )^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}. $$
Put
$$x-\dfrac{1}{2} =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ 2}} \sin \alpha, \quad  y-\dfrac{1}{2} =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos \alpha, \quad \alpha \in [0, 2\pi].$$
But I think, It is not simple.

Comment: you forgot a square root:  $x - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \alpha$ ...

Comment: @orangeskid Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum equals $3$ achieved at $(x,y) = (1,1)$. You could use the trig substitution or Lagrange multipliers. It is not a trivial problem since, say, the minimum is not a nice expression